# Python: Best way to store the top ten numbers

Tags: python, numpy, object, scipy

I have the following problem: I do paramter tests and create for every single paramter combination a new object, which is replaced by the next object created with other paramters. The Object has an attribute jaccard coefficient and an attribute ID. In every step i want to store the jaccard coeeficient of the object. At the end i want the top ten jaccard coeefcient and their corresponding ID.

```
r=["%.2f" % r for r in np.arange(3,5,1)]
fs=["%.2f" % fs for fs in np.arange(2,5,1)]
co=["%.2f" % co for co in np.arange(1,5,1)]
frc_networks=[]

bestJC = []
bestPercent = []
best10Candidates = []
count = 0
for parameters in itertools.product(r,fs,co):

    args = parser.parse_args(["path1.csv","path2.csv","--r",parameters[0],"--fs",parameters[1],"--co",parameters[2]])

    if not os.path.isfile('FCR_Network_Coordinates_ID_{}_r_{}_x_{}_y_{}_z_{}_fcr_{}_co_{}_1.csv'.format(count, args.r, args.x, args.y, args.z, args.fs,args.co)):

        FRC_Network(count,args.p[0],args.p[1],args.x,args.y,args.z,args.r,args.fs,args.co)
```

The attributes can be called by FRC_Network.ID and FRC_Network.JC

Comment: Am I missing something or will simply sorting the list and then chopping off anything after the first ten elements do the trick? (NB: This is logarithmically more work than strictly necessary but I'm pretty sure you can afford that.)

Comment: Yeah i could sort the jaccard coeeficient list and chopp it off, but then i need the  indices to get the corresponding IDs in the list of the IDS.

Comment: I wouldn't bother keeping the entire list. I'd use [`heapq.heappushpop()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappushpop) to maintain just the ten largest as the `for` loop iterates. That way, there is never a ginormous list to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd use [`heapq.heappushpop()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappushpop) for this. That way, no matter how large your input set is, your data requirement is limited to a list of 10 tuples.

Note the use of tuples to keep the `JC` and `ID` parameters. Since the comparisons are lexicographic, this will always sort by `JC`.

Also, note that the final call to `.sort()` is optional. If you just want the ten best, skip the call. If you want the ten best in order, keep the call.

```
import heapq

#UNTESTED
best = []
for parameters in itertools.product(r,fs,co):
    # ...
    if len(best) < 10:
        heapq.heappush(best, (FRC_Network.JC, FRC_Network.ID))
    else:
        heapq.heappushpop(best, (FRC_Network.JC, FRC_Network.ID))
best.sort(reverse=True)
```

Here is a tested version that demonstrates the concept:

```
import heapq
import random
from pprint import pprint

best = []
for ID in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ':
    JC = random.randint(0, 100)
    if len(best) < 10:
        heapq.heappush(best, (JC, ID))
    else:
        heapq.heappushpop(best, (JC, ID))
pprint(best)
```

Result:

```
[(81, 'E'),
 (82, 'd'),
 (83, 'G'),
 (92, 'i'),
 (95, 'Z'),
 (100, 'p'),
 (89, 'q'),
 (98, 'a'),
 (96, 'z'),
 (97, 'O')]
```

Comment: Nice, i will test it :)